# The resulting .iso doesn't work - MultiCD

Tags: live-cd, live-usb, livedvd

Burning a separate CD for each distribution (Ubuntu, Kubuntu etc.) is cumbersome. I found [MultiCD](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/) which promises me to have a single DVD which can hold several distributions. It is very great tool.

**Main Problem :** The resulting .iso created from multicd doesn't work in a USB pen drive through I haven't tested it in a DVD. Running the .iso through pen drive (I mean booting from pen drive) doesn't work. I cannot even run it in live mode or can install it.

**Concern :** I think if I burn the .iso to a DVD then might it will work. But considering it doesn't work in the pen drive, Will it work on the DVD?

So how to fix it? If you know other method to make a multi CD/DVD then please tell me.

Comment: I don't see how this pertains to ASK! Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel when you have Remastersys, Reconstructor, Mklivecd and Ubuntu Customization Kit.

Comment: @aking1012 My final destination is DVD but the .iso should also work in a USB flash drive.

Comment: @aking1012 I tried it in the virtual box but I got a error "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comments into the answer:

Okay, if you need an ISO and a thumb drive try it out in a VM.  If it tells you you're using the wrong architecture, that's probably what's giving you the kernel panic.  Try the procedure again with i686 or i386 isos.  It's the same thing you did before.  See the difference?

[image]

Comment: "Try the procedure again with i686 isos." How?

Comment: You mean 32 -bit live images?

Comment: I searched through the internet and found that visualization is necessary to run a 64 - bit OS. My processor doesn't support  visualization that's why I am getting that error. BTW I have only 64-bit images of Ubuntu 11.04 and Ubuntu 11.10. I have a slow connection and it will take days to download 32 bit images...! Did you know other methods to make a multi CD?

Comment: then burn the iso and test it, if it works i'll keep going on troubleshooting migrating to a thumbdrive.  if the shell script is broken, you should look at xbluerider's suggestions

Comment: Looks like xbluerider's suggestion is my only hope..... BTW thanks